# External HDD is read-only

Tags: debian, mount, external-hdd

When I mount an external HDD, it is read-only (ext4).

Folder permissions: `/media/user user:user (777)`

Permissions on the folder `/media/user/disk user:user (777)`, but when mounted, rights become `/media/user/disk root:root (755)`. Mount from Debian desktop icon (i.e. udisks2).

mount | grep

`/dev/sdb1 on /media/user/disk type ext4 (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,uhelper=udisks2)`

In order not to manually do remount each time, in which rules you need to specify to be mounted as user, not root

Comment: How are you mounting the HDD? What does `mount | grep /disk` show? Please [edit] your post to add new information, properly formatted. Information added via comments is hard for you to format, hard for us to read and ignored by future readers. Please click [edit] and add that vital information to your question so all the facts we need are in the question. Please don't use Add Comment, since that's our uplink to you. All facts about your system should go in the Question with [edit].

Comment: Ah, the never ending https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=15875

Comment: @ArtemS.Tashkinov Thanks for the link. I tried to disable the ACL through formatting (removing the acl from /etc/mke2fs.conf), through noacl to fstab, through tune2fs, but still mounts as root:root 755.

Comment: This feature is not currently implemented.